# How do i access data that has been uploaded to datastore via azure file share?

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-files

Uploaded a bunch of csvs to azure file share data store. how can I access the data from the datastore in a script?

```
#upload csv to datastore
datastore = ws.get_default_datastore()
path='path'
target=(datastore,path)
ds=Dataset.File.upload_directory(data_loacation,target,overwrite=True,show_progress = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Create an Azure Files Datastore. Below is the sample code to create Azure Files Datastore.

```
from azure.ai.ml.entities import AzureFileDatastore
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient

ml_client = MLClient.from_config()

store = AzureFileDatastore(
    name="file-example",
    description="Datastore pointing to an Azure File Share.",
    account_name="mytestfilestore",
    file_share_name="my-share",
    credentials={
        "account_key": "XXXxxxXXXxXXXXxxXXXXXxXXXXXxXxXXXXxxxxxXXxxxxxxXXXxXXX"
    },
)

ml_client.create_or_update(store)
```

For more information follow this [Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-datastore?tabs=cli-identity-based-access%2Ccli-adls-identity-based-access%2Csdk-azfiles-accountkey%2Ccli-adlsgen1-identity-based-access#create-an-azure-files-datastore)